# Ansible can't loop through subelements in variables files

Tags: ansible

I have the following user lists in separated files.
The idea behind this is to create multiple users and assign them to different user groups.
To make it easier, I shortened the list. I reality they include passwords and etc.
First variables file

```
userlist-os:
  group: os
  users:
    - comment: Test User
      username: ostest1
      user_id: 9404
      user_state: present
    - comment: Test User
      username: ostest2
      user_id: 9405
      user_state: present
```

Second variables file

```
userlist-zos:
  group: zos
  users:
    - comment: Test User1
      username: zostest1
      user_id: 9204
      user_state: present
    - comment: Test User2
      username: zostest2
      user_id: 9205
      user_state: present
```

This is how my playbook looks like:

```
- name: test
  hosts: all
  user: root
  vars_files: 
   - [userlist-zos.yml]
   - [userlist-os.yml]
  tasks:
  - name: Create user accounts
    user:
      name: "{{ item.users.username }}"
      update_password: on_create
      uid: "{{ item.users.user_id }}"
      shell: /bin/bash
      create_home: yes
      group: "{{ item.group }}"
      state: present
      comment: "{{ item.users.comment }}"
    when: item.users.user_state == 'present'
    with_items:
      - "{{ userlist-os }}"
      - "{{ userlist-zos }}"
```

The problem is that I'm not getting into the sub elements of users`(variable username is undefined)`, but when I set an index like this `name: "{{ item.users.0.username }}"` I do get the first username from each file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, item.users are lists of users, they are not dictionaries. Therefore they don't have username field, they have list elements which have that field instead. You were able to access to first element of the list with "item.users.0.username".  What I suggest you to do is to access these nested variables with an include_task variable as follows:

main.yaml

```yaml
- name: Trial
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
     # YOUR VARS
  tasks:
  - name: Create user accounts
    include_tasks: helper.yml
    with_items:
      - "{{ userlistos }}"
      - "{{ userlistzos }}"
    loop_control:
     loop_var: list
```

helper.yml

```yaml
- name: Create user accounts
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    update_password: on_create
    uid: "{{ item.user_id }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    create_home: yes
    group: "{{ list.group }}"
    state: present
    comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
  when: item.user_state == 'present'
  with_items:
    - "{{list.users}}"
```